# What is the angle at which the time of sliding is least?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

> A small body starts sliding down from the top of a wedge with base $2.10 \; \mathrm{m}$, and whose angle of inclination is $\alpha$. The coefficient of friction between the body and the wedge surface is $k = 0.140$. At
>   what value of the angle $\alpha$ will the time of sliding be the least? What
>   will it be equal to?

The question is from Problems in General Physics by I.E Irodov, and I cannot understand why the answer cannot be just less than $90°$, so there's 
negligible friction and the component of gravity pulling it down is maximum, but it still "slides"?

Comment: There's a requirement that the sliding traverse 2.1 meters horizontally (the base). A 90 degree slide won't cover any horizontal distance.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the *base length*, not the length of the slide, is given. So the larger the angle is, the longer the slide, approaching infinity as the angle approaches 90°. You need to find the angle at which the benefit from having a steeper slope is overcome by the drawback of having a longer path when the angle is increased further.

Answer (score -2):

If its 90 degrees wedge doesnt exist 
The way to go about this problem is 
Distance$=2.1/\cos\alpha$
Acceleration $= mg\cos\alpha k-mg\sin\alpha$
Now use formula

$$S=\frac 1 2 at^2$$

Now $t$ is in terms of alpha
Differenciate it to zero